# Use s-expression in OCaml utop

Tags: ocaml

I am learning OCaml with a book titled as "Real World OCaml" and so far it works well.

I have a problem with sexp and Sexplib.

```
# module type M = sig
#   type t with sexp
# end;;
```

This is a textbook example but I have a syntax error in utop, with `with` word underlined. `Core.Std` is open.

Can anyone explain this? I doubt if they have changed language syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace  "`with sexp`"  with `[@@deriving sexp]`; this also requires the `ppx_sexp_conv` rewriter. Alternatively, you can also use `ppx_jane`, which includes all Janestreet PPX rewriters (and is automatically used when you use the `corebuild` command).

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "core";;
# #require "ppx_sexp_conv";;
# open Core.Std;;

# module type M = sig type t [@@deriving sexp]  end;;
module type M =
  sig
    type t
    val t_of_sexp : Sexplib.Sexp.t -> t
    val sexp_of_t : t -> Sexplib.Sexp.t
  end
```

Explanation :

http://blogs.janestreet.com/extension-points-or-how-ocaml-is-becoming-more-like-lisp/

Answer (score 1):

*Real World OCaml* was published in 2013 and understandably some examples don't work with the latest version of OCaml, especially the syntax extension part.

As a learner, if you don't mind rolling back to an older version, e.g. 4.02.1, you can run most example programs provided by the book.

```
opam switch 4.02.1
```

After switching the opam version, you might need to reinstall everything you need again, for example, utop.

Answer (score 0):

Real Worl Ocaml relies on ocaml 4.01.0 (see in the prologue). 
With this version of ocaml, you need to include Sexplib.syntax first (which is not part of Core)

```
#require "sexplib.syntax";;
```

For having this, you also need to install type_conv that will pick the right revision of sexplib (111.25.00 instead of 112.01.00).

```
>opam install type_conv
```

Comment: For me your solution doesn't work, maybe can you check it. Have a good day (bonne année 2017).

Comment: hmmm, I recheck again and it works with ocaml 4.01.0 (prior to that, I perform opam update & upgrade). Bonne année too !!!

Comment: :Your solution seems better than mine, i use ocaml 4.02.2. Can you show us all the begining of the utop's instructions ?

Comment: there is nothing else than the line I quoted above. The .ocamlinit file contains only #use "top_find";;...